# Can you still play WoW on an external hard drive?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it still possible to put the whole WoW folder on an external hard drive an just execute the .exe file (on the external drive itself) since the Blizzard Launcher came out (where all games are started from)? Or will it force me to first install/download the Blizzard Launcher on the computer?

Comment: According to [this post](http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/9793020206), it is possible.

Comment: Idle curiosity: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff obviously I can't speak for OP but three valid reasons I can think of are a) if you didn't have enough space on your internal drive you might want to do this, b) if it was more convenient for you to carry the drive around rather than download the game each time (maybe you often borrow computers), and c) if you had a slow or capped internet connection and (again) didn't want to download the game each time.

Comment: and, as someone mentioned in a comment below, your external drive might be faster than your internal drive. unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @strugee those reasons seem logical.  I guess they never occurred to me as I was never in any of those situations back when I played WoW.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff never played WoW, never been in that situation either, although I work with software projects that have to consider users in those conditions. guess I just have a different perspective :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it will be possible to do this, the easiest way to do it would be to simply (re)install World of Warcraft making sure to opt for the "advanced" option rather than typical install. This will let you pick an install directory.

At that point you will be able to browse to the external hard drive and create a new folder called "WoW" and install!

I run all of my steam games from an external SSD, it is quite possible to achieve.

Comment: @RandomDisplayName The only factor to account for is the speed of the external HD and what kind of link it has with your PC (usb 2, 3 or eSata). The main thing affected by this will be the loading times.

Comment: In the battle.net launcher app is a setting to move the wow folder, no need to reinstall it.

Comment: You can actually just copy the folder in windows explorer. I've always done this for my copy of wow.

Comment: @corsiKa: Blizzard Launcher/Updater won't like that

Comment: Sure it does. You just tell it where you moved it to. But you only need the updater when you actually do updates, and you can't log in without the new update. So it knows where to find its own updater anyway. I always go straight to the client, not the launcher.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I've ran WoW off an external for ages. Very handy when friends want to play - you can also use it to make a copy on their computer. No problem comes up when running it. Updates work, as well as the copy on the friends computers, where the game was not deliberately installed.

Comment: Does not work for network drive :/